# Use jQuery with React component

Tags: jquery, node.js, reactjs

I want to add jquery to my react component but I have an error :

> TypeError: _jquery2.default.ajax is not a function
>      at render (C:\xampp\htdocs\formation\delicious-server\tmp\webpack:\src\routes\Xml.js:10:5)

My code is really simple :

```
var React = require('React');
import $ from 'jquery';

var Xml = React.createClass({
render: function(){

    $.ajax({
          url: 'config.xml',
          dataType: 'xml',
          cache: false,
          success: function(data) {
            data = xmlToJson(data);
            console.log(data);
          }.bind(this)
        });
        return (<p>data</p>);
  }
});

module.exports = Xml;
```

I did a `npm install --save jquery`, it's installed but it still doesn't work. How should I do please

Comment: Import seems valid. What's in `$`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The render function is for the HTML/React components that will be rendered on the page, for stuff like this, you will want to use [componentDidMount](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) but if you are fetching data, then you may also want to consider looking at something like Redux which can help with removing the need for jQuery and handle stuff like async loading of data.

Answer (score 0):

you should not used function in render method, use componentWillMount method for ajax call function before component is mount

```
    var Xml = React.createClass({
      componentWillMount: function() {

       $.ajax({
          url: 'config.xml',
          dataType: 'xml',
          cache: false,
          success: function(data) {
            data = xmlToJson(data);
            console.log(data);
          }.bind(this)
        });
      },

      render:function(){
        <p>data</p>
      }
    });

module.exports = Xml;
```